# Should we close as duplicate when the new question is more concise and general?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

This question has been prompted by the suggestion that [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/3447/8) is a dupe of [this one](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1234/8). Substantively it is, but the solutions posted as answers are non-overlapping. Also in the first question, the test for do nothing is missing data, not a numerical logical test, and some solutions are specific to that case. They are not answers to the second question.

I feel that the newer question is more canonical and general and thus more likely to be found by future Googlers.

Is there an argument for defining duplicate narrowly and therefore not closing in cases like this?

Comment: That's a good question, and a good part of why I hesitated to close it myself.  To add a tag-along question, what is the community position on closing the *older* question in a case like this?

Comment: Closing the older question seems unfair, too.

Comment: I think the older question has a number of useful answers to that specific question, which is useful as a learning tool as an example.  The new question is much more general and easier to parse quickly, and thus should be left up (in my opinion... but I'm slightly biased as it is my question).

Comment: @Andrew, closed does not mean deleted.  The question will still be "up" whether or not it is closed.  Nevertheless I am now favoring leaving it open myself.

Comment: While closed does not imply deleted, it does indicate that it is likely to be deleted eventually. So, I'm in favor of keeping the question open.

Comment: If we take the route of closing one of them, we need to have some sort of marker to say close-but-not-delete, eg locking.